# Automated way to derive files within rails public directory without knowing the file names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let us say that I have a rails app, and I have multiple files stored in the rails app within the `public/images` directory.

**Question:** Is there a way an end user could get access to images stored within the `public` directory without the user happening to brute-force guess what the image file names are?

- For example: is there some trick where a user could list all the files within the `public` directory of a rails app?

I am aware that you **NEVER** store sensitive files inside the `public` directory because it has no access control.  I'm just curious if it is possible to access the `public` directory contents in some clever way without already knowing the directory/file structure.  I'm wondering if there is a clever way to *derive* the directory/file structure within the public directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If*, and that's a big "if", your server is configured correctly and does not have directory indexing turned on then there's no way you can enumerate a list of files. In order for this to be the case you must know how to configure your server properly. Many servers, especially Apache `httpd`, turn on directory indexing by default so you must explicitly disable this. You must also periodically test that it's disabled as sometimes a simple software update can revert settings to defaults.

This comes with the caveat that there is no guarantee that a high-impact vulnerability that allows directory traversal and enumeration may not occur in the future. Anything in `public` can be retrieved directly if the name is known. Any other file can be retrieved if there's a remote-code execution bug (RCE). Though these are very rare, it has happened to Rails before and could happen again.

The attack you want to defend against is dictionary attacks, or brute-force enumeration if there's a pattern to your ID values. Using a random UUID creates way too huge a space to search, but a short name like `/profile-images/xBv.png` invites people to probe.